# React Native open Source sdk

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, videocall

Hi i am developing a social app using react-native.Most part is done. I want to embed a video calling feature upto 4 participants. Is there any open source sdk which i can use for this purpose?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I have not personally tried.

https://github.com/EnableX/One-to-One-Video-Calling-Open-Source-React-Native-Application

Comment: thanks for commenting, but i got my solution via janus webrtc